# Spring Boot 2.2.1 Create two jar's while Build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

I am working on `Spring boot` version `2.2.1.RELEASE`.While building my project two jar's will created having types `executable jar file` and `original file` as given below

[image]

The reason for this is

> Maven first builds my project and packages my classes and
>   resources into a jar (${artifactId}.jar) file.
>
> Then, repackaging happens. In this goal, all the dependencies
>   mentioned in the pom.xml are packaged inside a new WAR
>   (${artifactId}.jar) and the previously generated war is renamed to
>   ${artifactId}.jar.original.

Pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
              <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>repackage</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>         
            <configuration>    
                <mainClass>com.data.MainService</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can we avoid to create `ORIGINAL File` type jar file.

Is there any disable /excluding technique available in maven.

Am also tried following `<build>`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>                         
                <configuration>    
                    <mainClass>com.data.MainService</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the implementation jar.original is expected. Nothing to worry about.

Re packaging creates new jar file and renames old one to jar.original

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins.html#build-tool-plugins-repackage-implementation